# Get the extension of file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have files with "multiple" extension , for better manipulation I would like to create new folder for each last extension but first I need to retrieve the last extension.

Just for example lets assume i have file called `info.tar.tbz2` how could I get "tbz2" ?

One way that comes to my mind is using `cut -d "."` but in this case I would need to specify `-f` parameter of the last column, which I don't know how to achieve.

What is the fastest way to do it?

Comment: `f=info.tar.tbz2; ext=${f##*.}`, to put everything after the last `.` into `ext` without the performance expense of external tools such as `awk` or `sed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use awk,

```
awk -F. '{print $NF}' file
```

or

sed,

```
$ echo 'info.tar.tbz2' | awk -F. '{print $NF}'
tbz2
$ echo 'info.tar.tbz2' | sed 's/.*\.//'
tbz2
```

Comment: how could i do this dynamicly on unknown amount of files?

Comment: do you want to rename files?

Comment: no i just need the extension